# Vegan package installation error in R

Tags: r, installation, package

Hi have been trying to install the "vegan" package but I get errors:

```
 >install.packages("vegan-package")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---

Warning message:
package ‘vegan-package’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)
```

I have also tried this:

```
> install.packages("vegan_2.3-0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
ERROR: dependency 'permute' is not available for package 'vegan'
* removing 'C:/Users/Documents/R/R-3.1.2/library/vegan'
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/Users/Documents/R/R-3.1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Documents\R\R-3.1.2\library" "vegan_2.3-0.tar.gz"'       had status 1 
2: In install.packages("vegan_2.3-0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘vegan_2.3-0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any other suggestions on how to get access to this library?

Thanks very much.

Comment: try `install.packages("vegan")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
install.packages("vegan")
```

will get you there.

Comment: It was simpler than what I thought!Thanks!It worked!